# Counting nulls in PySpark dataframes with total rows and columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to write a query to count all the `null` values in a large dataframe using PySpark. After reading in the dataset, I am doing this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_agg = df.agg(*[F.count(F.when(F.isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])

df_countnull_agg.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv(path)
```

This works fine and the `df_agg` dataframe gives me something like this:

```
#+--------+--------+--------+
#|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|
#+--------+--------+--------+
#|      15|      56|      18|
#+--------+--------+--------+
```

What I want to do is to also add two columns at the end of the dataframe for `total_rows` and `total_columns` so I can run some calculations after writing to a `.csv` file. I know I can get the numbers from the dataframe like this:

```
total_rows = df.count()
total_columns = len(df.columns)
```

I want to add those two numbers into columns that would result in a dataframe like this, and then write it to a `.csv` like I before:

```
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
#|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|t_rows  |t_cols  |
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
#|      15|      56|      18|     500|      20|
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

What I'm concerned about is runtime, since counting the `nulls` takes a bit of time, and then calculating the shape of the dataframe and adding that to the final df for output. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get count of total rows, you could do that inside the aggregate by counting values of `F.lit(1)`, and then you could to get `count` of total columns by using withColumn to create a new column with literal(`lit`) as `len` of `df.columns`.

```
df.agg(*[F.count(F.when(F.isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns], F.count(F.lit(1)).alias("t_rows"))\
   .withColumn("t_cols", F.lit(len(df.columns))).show()

+-----+----+--------+------+------+
|query|href|position|t_rows|t_cols|
+-----+----+--------+------+------+
|    3|   2|       0|    12|     3|
+-----+----+--------+------+------+
```

Comment: Getting the count of rows using this method doesn't seem to work, it's returning 0. Some of the columns in this dataframe are not populated. Is there a way to use the index of the dataframe to get the overall row count and not use the count for a specific column?

Comment: @codingenthusiast I have updated solution. The row count was giving zero because that column prob has all nulls and count does not include nulls, so In agg I basically do a count of new column with all 1 literals(basically creating my own index). this will be more fast then running df.count()

Comment: Thank you, yes that is faster to run and does the job!